# IF Statement on excel macro coding

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to Macro coding and as per the File we have there is already an existing excel formula on it. but since I want to reduce the file size. can I you guys help me how I can create Macro code for this Formula. as sample formula would help.

```
=IF(('Sheet2'!H5=""),"",IF('sheet2'!H5="Notification","PENDING",""))
```

Note: "Notification is on sheet 3, Column G5.

Comment: Did you try `=IF('sheet2'!H5="Notification","PENDING","")`. The first condition is useless.

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stuck. You are not showing any effort. Did you try to use the Macro Recorder?

Answer (score 0):

Translated to VBA it would be something like this:

```
if Range("H5").value = "Notification" then
    Range("H5").value = "PENDING"
end if
```

Comment: how about this.  =IF(A4="","",VLOOKUP(LEFT(A4,10),'Sheet3'!$B:$C,2,FALSE)).....................................Note that A4 is in Sheet 2 and